# WCF problem with POSTs using ssl (https)

Tags: wcf, ssl, post, https, webhttp

I currently have a webHttp binding WCF restful service, it works great over http, I can make Post of large sizes due to my webconfig settings, now I am trying to  use it  over https (ssl), now my gets work fine, but my posts dont, it doesnt work when the  file size is over a certain amount, i was wondering why this could be since my webconfig specifies a larger size and it works good over http, here is my relevant webconfig.. any suggestions

Thanks

```
<system.serviceModel>
<client>
  <endpoint binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="webHttp"
    contract="PrimeStreamInfoServices.IService1" name="Client" />
</client>
<bindings>
  <webHttpBinding>
    <binding name="webHttp" maxBufferSize="15000000" maxBufferPoolSize="15000000"
      maxReceivedMessageSize="15000000">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="15000000" maxStringContentLength="10000000" 
        maxArrayLength="15000000" maxBytesPerRead="15000000" maxNameTableCharCount="10000000" />
      <security mode="None">
        <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
          realm="string" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </webHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<services>
  <service behaviorConfiguration="PrimeStreamInfoServices.Service1Behavior"
    name="PrimeStreamInfoServices.Service1">
    <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding"
      bindingConfiguration="webHttp" contract="PrimeStreamInfoServices.IService1" />
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
  </service>
</services>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="PrimeStreamInfoServices.Service1Behavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
      <serviceCredentials>
        <!--
        <serviceCertificate storeLocation="LocalMachine" storeName="My" x509FindType="FindBySubjectName" findValue="TempCa" />
          -->
      </serviceCredentials>

    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<diagnostics>

  <messageLogging logMalformedMessages="true"  logMessagesAtServiceLevel="true"
    logMessagesAtTransportLevel="true" />

</diagnostics>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want to use webHttpBinding over SSL then you have configure your binding to use transport security like:

```
<security mode="Transport">
```

This [link](http://weblogs.asp.net/srkirkland/archive/2008/02/20/wcf-bindings-needed-for-https.aspx) provides some details with sample config to deal with the following error:

> Could not find a base address that matches scheme http for the
>   endpoint with binding WebHttpBinding. Registered base address schemes
>   are [https]

**Sample config from the blog:**

```
<system.serviceModel>
<behaviors>    
 <endpointBehaviors>
  <behavior name="TestServiceAspNetAjaxBehavior">
   <enableWebScript />
  </behavior>
 </endpointBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" />
<services>
 <service name="TestService">
  <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="TestServiceAspNetAjaxBehavior"
   binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="webBinding" contract="TestService" />
 </service>
</services>
 <bindings>
   <webHttpBinding>
     <binding name="webBinding">
       <security mode="Transport">
       </security>
     </binding>
   </webHttpBinding>
 </bindings>
</system.serviceModel>
```