# Cross Domain jQuery AJAX request to WCF - 405 Method not allowed

Tags: wcf, web-services, rest, jquery

I am building simple WCF web service for my mobile web app.
I am stack at the point of making the `$.ajax` request to WCF which comes back with `405 - Method not allow`, even though when I do `http://http://localhost:35798/RestServiceImpl.svc/json/23` I can see result of the `ReturnJSONData()` in the browser.

I went through 100's of different post, but none of the answer fixed my problem.

**AJAX Request**

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "http://localhost:35798/RestServiceImpl.svc/json/34",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8", 
    success: function(data) {
    console.log(data);
    },
});
```

**IRestServiceImpl.cs**

```
namespace RestService{
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IRestServiceImpl
    {
        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(
            Method = "GET",
            ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
            BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped,
            UriTemplate = "json/{id}"
            )]
        string ReturnJSONData(string id);
    }
}
```

**RestServiceImpl.svs.cs**

```
namespace RestService {
    public class RestServiceImpl : IRestServiceImpl {
        public string ReturnJSONData(string id) {
            return "You requested product " + id;
        }
    }
}
```

**WebConfig**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>

    <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
</system.web>
<system.serviceModel>
<services>
    <service name="RestService.RestServiceImpl" behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehaviour">
        <endpoint address ="" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="RestService.IRestServiceImpl" behaviorConfiguration="web">
        </endpoint>
    </service>
</services>

<behaviors>
    <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="ServiceBehaviour">
            <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
            <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        </behavior>
    </serviceBehaviors>
    <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="web">
            <webHttp/>
        </behavior>
    </endpointBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<standardEndpoints>
    <webHttpEndpoint>
        <standardEndpoint name=""
        helpEnabled="true"
        automaticFormatSelectionEnabled="true"
        defaultOutgoingResponseFormat ="Json"
        crossDomainScriptAccessEnabled="true"/>
    </webHttpEndpoint>
</standardEndpoints>
</system.serviceModel>
<system.webServer>
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
</system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

**Any suggestion much appreciated.**

Comment: Are you sure that the URL isn't supposed to be a relative path...?
url: "/RestServiceImpl.svc/json/34",

Comment: You probably find that it's a browser security setting that prevents you from doing that in javascript. though accessing WCF services in JS isn't something I've done before

Comment: Did you check those links: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41155/wcf-service-returning-method-not-allowed 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3057124/jquery-ajax-call-to-wcf-service-returning-method-not-allowed-405?rq=1

Comment: @ThiagoCustodio - yes, I also had a go with WebGet - no success..

Comment: @Koenyn - web app will be running on a different domain than web service. So path for sure will not be relative.