# Could not find a base address that matches scheme https

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf

Error: `Could not find a base address that matches scheme https for the endpoint with binding WebHttpBinding. Registered base address schemes are [http].`

I've searched other answers and tried out different things, but my web service still isn't working. Note: I am new at this, but have experience in dev/web service. I only need the service to run on HTTPS, btw.

Web.config:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <webHttpBinding>
            <binding name="bindingHTTPS" crossDomainScriptAccessEnabled="true">
                <security mode="Transport">
                    <transport clientCredentialType="None"></transport>
                </security>
            </binding>
            <binding name="httpbind" crossDomainScriptAccessEnabled="true"></binding>
        </webHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <services>
        <service name="Personnel.Personnel" behaviorConfiguration="personnelBehavior">
            <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="bindingHTTPS" contract="Personnel.IPersonnel" behaviorConfiguration="web"></endpoint>
            <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="httpbind" contract="Personnel.IPersonnel" behaviorConfiguration="web"></endpoint>
        </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
        <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior name="personnelBehavior">
                <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
                <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
            </behavior>
            <behavior>
                <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the values below to false before deployment -->
                <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
                <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
                <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
            </behavior>
        </serviceBehaviors>
        <endpointBehaviors>
            <behavior name="web">
                <webHttp/>
            </behavior>
        </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <protocolMapping>
        <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
    </protocolMapping>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
</system.serviceModel>
```

It worked fine until I added another method? So now I have two methods? in my web service:

```
[WebGet(UriTemplate="createOffboardTask/{resourceName}/{lastDay}/{submitter}",ResponseFormat=WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle=WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped)]
        public string createOffboardTask(string resourceName, string lastDay, string submitter)
        {
            //do some stuff
        }

[WebGet(UriTemplate = "createOnboardTask/{resourceName}/{firstDay}/{submitter}/{itemID}", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped)]
            public string createOnboardTask(string resourceName, string firstDay, string submitter, string itemID)
            {
                //do some stuff
            }
```

And I do have both operation contracts in the Ifile:

```
[OperationContract]
        string createOffboardTask(string resourceName, string lastDay, string submitter);

[OperationContract]
        string createOnboardTask(string resourceName, string firstDay, string submitter, string ID);
```

Comment: Is this service or Web hosted as HTTPS..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this to binding configuration.

```
<security mode="Transport">
```

Can refer this if you need [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2253558/wcf-problem-with-posts-using-ssl-https)